# Download xml file in R and how to write a R package in S5 class?

Tags: xml, r, package, r-s4

Two questions have confused me:

1. How do I download a 'xml' file in R console?
2. I want to make a R pcakage by 'S4 class' , but many functions I

still don't know,such as how to set the variables environment 'new.env' et

al;what I grasped are some fundamental functions;so,could any advices about

how to write R functions in 'S4' class,and intergrate them into a package ?

The question 1 are as follows:

I want to download a 'xml' file in

‘http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/downloads.jsp’

```
and the filename is 'msigdb_v5.0.xml' .
```

I don't want to download the file in my computer then parse it by 'XML' package;

I have tried as follows:

```
Method 1:  

    download.file('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/downloads.jsp','msigdb_v5.0.xml')

It showed :

    trying URL 'http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/downloads.jsp'

    Content type 'text/html' length 5070 bytes

    opened URL

    downloaded 5070 bytes

Method 2： 

    library(XML)

    path="http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/download_file.jsp?

    filePath=/resources/msigdb/5.0/msigdb_v5.0.xml"

    file=xmlParse(path)

It showed error:

    Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

    Bytes: 0xA9 0x20 0x32 0x30

    Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 68 and a

    Entity 'nbsp' not defined

    Entity 'nbsp' not defined

    Entity 'nbsp' not defined

    Entity 'nbsp' not defined

    Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 34 and div

    Opening and ending tag mismatch: html line 25 and body

    Extra content at the end of the document

    Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

               Bytes: 0xA9 0x20 0x32 0x30

           2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 68 and a

           3: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

           4: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

           5: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

           6: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

           7: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 34 and div

           8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: html line 25 and body

           9: Extra content at the end of the document

Method 3.

     library(RCurl)

     path='http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/download_file.jsp?

     filePath=/resources/msigdb/5.0/msigdb_v5.0.xml'

     readHTMLTable(path,encoding="UTF-8")

  also,method 3 was error again!
```

Comment: Looks like a log-in is required for that site. It does not seem you've made any attempt to supply the required e-mail address. Plus, you should ask one question at a time on Stack Overflow, especially when they are so different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices.  I have registered  an e-mail -----msigdb@163.com , which you can log-in. I want to know if you can download this file by R console. Thank you .^_^